# Grouping the object by key for Chartjs bar chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I'm trying to create bar chart using Chart.js. I got stuck trying to create grouped bar chart based on the status per user. So here's the data:

```
[{statusId: 0, firstName: "Joe", status: "appealed", count: 1},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Jane", status: "approved", count: 100},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Smith", status: "approved", count: 63},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Mike", status: "approved", count: 63},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Ken", status: "approved", count: 35},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Kim", status: "approved", count: 193},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Joe", status: "approved", count: 1},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Jane", status: "closed", count: 1},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Joe", status: "concluded", count: 1},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Jane", status: "denied", count: 6},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Smith", status: "denied", count: 9},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Mike", status: "denied", count: 1},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Mark", status: "denied", count: 8},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Ken", status: "denied", count: 2},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Kim", status: "denied", count: 20},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Joe", status: "denied", count: 2},
{statusId: 0, firstName: "Joe", status: "transferred", count: 1}]
```

From this data, I need to create a chart for users in x-axis with count of each status for the user. It can be easily done in Chartjs by having array of datasets like the following:

```
datasets:[{
      data: [//some counts for a group],
     },
     {
       data: [// counts for another group],
     }
    // and so on
}]
```

The problem is I'll need to group these data based on the status. So, one solution I can think of is:

```
angular.forEeach(data, function(val)){ 
   switch(val.status){
       case 'approved':
        // add count to an approved count array
        break;
       case 'appealed':
       // add count to appealed count array
       break;
   }

}
```

But I think there're problems with this one. What if they create another status e.g. pending. Then I'll have to go back and change the code. Is there anyway I can group the objects by status and create an array of count data for each group that I can then use in datasets?

I just signed up for javascript course in pluralsight, so it'll still take me a while to learn advanced javascript. In the meantime, can anyone show me the proper and efficient way to solve this puzzle?

### EXAMPLE

Chart.js requires data to be in the following format:

```
var data = {
    labels: ['Joe', 'Jane', 'Smith', 'Mike', 'Ken', 'Kim', 'Mark'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Appealed',
            fillColor: '#382765',
            data: [1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        },
        {
            label: 'Approved',
            fillColor: '#7BC225',
            data: [1, 100, 63, 63, 35, 193,0]
        },
        {
            label: 'Denied',
            fillColor: '#2196F3',
            data: [2, 6, 9, 1, 2, 20, 8]
        },

    ]

}
```

So, what's happening here is for each `item` in `labels` there's a `count` for the `status` i.e. `label` in `data` array inside `datasets` array. For e.g.: `data` array for `Appealed` `label`: `1` is the `count` of `appealed` for `Joe` and rest is 0 for all other users.

Comment: does the datasets' data have an order or is it just the same as the given data? is the data sorted by status?

Comment: It is the same as the given data. If it helps, I can make it ordered by status or any other criteria.

Comment: You could use lodash's [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) function, if I understood your issue correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a hash table as reference to the array with the same `status` and another hash table for indices of the names. then build the labels array and datasets.

```js
var raw = [{ statusId: 0, firstName: "Joe", status: "appealed", count: 1 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Jane", status: "approved", count: 100 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Smith", status: "approved", count: 63 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Mike", status: "approved", count: 63 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Ken", status: "approved", count: 35 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Kim", status: "approved", count: 193 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "JoeJoe", status: "approved", count: 1 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Jane", status: "closed", count: 1 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Joe", status: "concluded", count: 1 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Jane", status: "denied", count: 6 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Smith", status: "denied", count: 9 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Mike", status: "denied", count: 1 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Mark", status: "denied", count: 8 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Ken", status: "denied", count: 2 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Kim", status: "denied", count: 20 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Joe", status: "denied", count: 2 }, { statusId: 0, firstName: "Joe", status: "transferred", count: 1 }],
    nameIndices = Object.create(null),
    statusHash = Object.create(null),
    data = { labels: [], datasets: [] };

raw.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!(o.firstName in nameIndices)) {
        nameIndices[o.firstName] = data.labels.push(o.firstName) - 1;
        data.datasets.forEach(function (a) { a.data.push(0); });
    }
    if (!statusHash[o.status]) {
        statusHash[o.status] = { label: o.status, fillcolor: 'f00', data: data.labels.map(function () { return 0; }) };
        data.datasets.push(statusHash[o.status]);
    }
    statusHash[o.status].data[nameIndices[o.firstName]] = o.count;
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick! this seems like what I need. I'm reading the code and learning from it. I'll apply this to my app and see if I have any more questions. I'll mark this as answer once I understand everything. This is awesome!!

Comment: Actually, it's quite not what I was anticipating. Turns out, although it gives me in the format I needed, it's not matching up with the `firstName`. And I've been trying a lot to figure this out. Could you please help me figuring this out? the chart should have `firstname` in x-axis. So, the length of datasets array should be equal to number of users. And their status and count should be within that object.

Comment: So, the unique `firstname` should be in `legends` array outside of `datasets` array, if that makes sense.

Comment: please add the wanted data in an example.

Comment: I added the example in the original question.

Comment: That did it, and I understand what you did. I'll be reading on .map() function a bit. seems useful. Thank you.