# Right way to Plot Dynamic Grouped Bar chart.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, chart.js

I have the following data which should be shown in a grouped bar chart using chart.js:

- Average delivery days on the left side
- Week names at the bottom
- The route names beside each other per week name

My json data(not all data are here):

```
    {"data":[{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 2","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 2","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 3","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 4","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 4","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 4","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 5","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 5","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 5","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 5","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 5","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 6","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 6","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 6","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 6","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 6","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 7","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 7","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 7","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 7","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 7","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 8","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 8","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 8","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 8","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 8","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 9","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 9","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 9","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 9","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 9","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 10","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 10","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 10","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 10","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 10","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 11","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 11","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 11","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 11","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 11","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 12","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 12","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 12","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 12","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 12","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 13","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 13","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 13","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 13","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 13","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 14","Average_Delivery_Days":5},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 14","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 14","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 14","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 14","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 15","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 15","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 15","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 15","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 15","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 16","Average_Delivery_Days":5},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 16","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 16","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 16","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 16","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 17","Average_Delivery_Days":5},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 17","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 17","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 17","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 17","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 18","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 18","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 18","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 18","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 18","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 19","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 19","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 19","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 19","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 19","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 20","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 20","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 20","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 20","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 20","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 21","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 21","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 21","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 21","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 21","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 22","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 22","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 22","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 22","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 22","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 23","Average_Delivery_Days":19},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 23","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 23","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 23","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 23","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 24","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 24","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 24","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 24","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 24","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 25","Average_Delivery_Days":5},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 25","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 25","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 25","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 25","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 26","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 26","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 26","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 26","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 26","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 27","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 27","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 27","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 27","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 27","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 28","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 28","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 28","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 28","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 28","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 29","Average_Delivery_Days":5},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 29","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 29","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 29","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 29","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2016 Week 30","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2016 Week 30","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2016 Week 30","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2016 Week 30","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2016 Week 30","Average_Delivery_Days":1},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2017 Week 48","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2017 Week 48","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"C","week_name":"2017 Week 48","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2017 Week 48","Average_Delivery_Days":3},{"RouteID":"PQU","week_name":"2017 Week 49","Average_Delivery_Days":10},{"RouteID":"CAV","week_name":"2017 Week 49","Average_Delivery_Days":4},{"RouteID":"TSM","week_name":"2017 Week 49","Average_Delivery_Days":2},{"RouteID":"MK","week_name":"2017 Week 49","Average_Delivery_Days":1}],"filter_by":"Weekly"}
```

But I just can't get it right since based on my understanding, the route names should be the column names in order to make it right.

Wrong Graph:
[image]

Right Graph:
[image]

And my sample query:

```
SELECT [RouteID], 
CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]) as varchar) + ' Week ' + CAST(DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]) AS varchar) AS week_name,
AVG(DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(date, [UnloadDate]), CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]))) as Average_Delivery_Days 
FROM [CARGODB].[dbo].[Cargo_Transactions] 
WHERE [DeliveryDate] IS NOT NULL AND [DeliveryDate] != 0 
AND CONVERT(date, [DeliveryDate]) BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE() 
AND [UnloadDate] IS NOT NULL AND [UnloadDate] != 0 AND [DeliveryDate] > [UnloadDate] 
AND [Deleted] = 0 and [StageID] = 'D' AND [RouteID] IN ('TSM', 'C', 'MK', 'CAV', 'PQU')
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]), [RouteID]
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,[DeliveryDate]), DATEPART(WEEK,[DeliveryDate]), Average_Delivery_Days desc
```

**My Chart.js Code:**

```
var date_created = [];
        var average_delivery_days = [];
        var route_name = [];
        var oss_new_customers = [];

        for(var i in data.data) {
            date_created.push(data.data[i]['week_name']);
            average_delivery_days.push(data.data[i]['Average_Delivery_Days']);
            route_name.push(data.data[i]['RouteID']);
        }

        var chartdata = {
            labels: date_created,
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: route_name,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 152, 219,1.0)',
                    data: average_delivery_days,
                    legend: {
                        onClick: function(e){
                            hidden:true
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        };

        ctx = $("#delivery_performance_chart");
        delivery_performance_barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartdata,
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    footerFontStyle: 'normal'
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            show: true
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            show: true
                        }
                    }]
                },
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive:true
            }
        });
```

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So for everyone who somehow encountered the same issue, here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44071802/grouping-the-object-by-key-for-chartjs-bar-chart) on where I got the answer. :)